# What does a set of pencils contain when we know that pencils are not physically present in the set?

Tags: set-theory

I have some pencils, markers and a mobile phone on my desk. I consider the pencils and think of them as forming a set to which they belong. This set is now a thing existing in its own right.

These pencils are not physically contained in my set. Anyone can do with them anything they want and those pencils would still be in my set.

Question -If pencils are not physically in my set, when I say 'my set contains these pencils', what is it that it contains?

Comment: In that case, it is not a set of pencils, it is the empty set.

Comment: The "set of" is a logical concept: it contains zero, one or more pencils depending on the number of pencils that are considered.

Comment: Outside math we have concepts (universal) that applies to objects. A concept is "meaningful" even when there are no objects instantiating it: the present King of France.

Comment: Every set has always existed. When you “make” your set, you’re really just pointing to some mathematical object. You can’t do anything to create or destroy sets or other mathematical objects. A set theorist doesn’t start working with a set and worry it will be gone before they can finish their problem. Mathematics becomes absolutely over-encumbered and shaky otherwise. How mathematics jives with your physical pencils and natural language is thornier. But sets are mathematical objects, period.

Answer (score 6):

You're being confused by overloaded terms. *Pencil* refers to the complex physical process on your desk that you can write with; to the radically simplified symbolic representation of that class of similar *pencil* processes that exists only in the mind; and to a particular instantiation of that symbolically represented class, which also exists only in the mind.

*Set of pencils* refers both to the complex physical process on your desk that you can separate nondestructively into several parts, each of which parts is represented in the mind as a particular instantiation of the class *pencil*; to the symbolic representation of that class of similar *set of pencils* processes, and to the particular instantiation of that symbolically represented class.

[See wiki: Map-Territory Relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation)

Answer (score 4):

[§5.2 of the SEP article on plural quantification reads](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plural-quant/#IncoPredArgu):

> ... “It is haywire to think that when you have some Cheerios, you are eating a set” (1984: 448–9 [1998a: 72]). What Boolos is suggesting here is that analyses which deny Ontological Innocence are likely to get the subject of plural predications wrong.

> The obvious response is to interpret plural predicates in a way which ensures that what we eat are *the elements* of a set and not the set itself.

A set of pencils does, then, contain some pencils as elements (when non-empty). Note that we here advert to the distinction between [pure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pure+set) and impure sets, where a set of pencils is impure (has elements that are not purely set-theoretic entities).

Another way to think of this is suggested by the apparent (or at least possible) [singleton](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/singleton)-[haecceity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/medieval-haecceity/) relation. [Womer[21]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8536604/) notes that:

> Rodriguez-Pereyra’s account of singleton membership may be correct, and it may even be possible to construe properties of grounding the existence of singletons in terms of haecceities.

In other words, thinking of an object's haecceity means thinking of an object as contained in its unique singleton. This would be like an abstract version of the [spotlight picture of attentionality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/attention/#SpoThe). So to say, anyone can move your pencils about without changing the set because their being in the set is equivalent to there being a disposition to represent them under the singleton/haecceity operation, which can be done even when the pencils are not directly next to each other (or on the same surface, or whatever otherwise physically indicates their containment).

Answer (score 3):

A set is a number of things considered together. The things being considered need not be physical objects, and they need not be colocated in any way. The name of the set is a label of sorts that refers to the things being considered.

When you say that your set 'contains' pencils, you are simply using a conventional way of saying that the pencils are the objects being considered together. In that sense of the word 'contain', the set does contain pencils.

I think your problem is that you are confusing two different uses of the word contain, one being the use I have described above, and the other denoting the quality of enclosing something physically, as in the bag contained a kilo of grapes.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using two different definitions of "contains" and you confused yourself because you used the same word for both definitions. Just use two different words and it will all be less confusing. Your set of pencils is not defined by a spatial location, and the pencils don't have to be located in any particular place to be "contained" in the set. "Being an element of the set" is not the same concept as "being located on the desk right now".

However, you can define a set that depends on location of objects in the real world.

But if these real-world objects are going to change location as time goes, then you should make the dependence on time explicit.

Define X(t) to be the set of pencils located on your desk at time t. Then X(0) is the set of pencils originally on your desk; and if your friend borrows a pencil between times 0 and 1, then X(1) will have fewer pencils than X(0).

There is no contradiction here - removing a pencil from your desk after time 0 did not change the definition of X(0), which is still the set of pencils that were on your desk at time 0.

On the other hand, if you are not interested in the evolution over time, and only interested in the set of pencils that were on your desk on 2023, june 23, 18:00, then call Y the set of all pencils that were on your desk on 2023, june 23, 18:00. Now if tomorrow your friend borrows a pencil, this will cause no contradiction; it will not change the definition of Y, which is the set of pencils that were on your desk yesterday at 18:00.